# XNA rendertarget sprite batch problem

Tags: xna-4.0, spritebatch, rendertargets

When using this code:

```
public static Texture2D ShowHealthBar(SpriteBatch spriteBatch,Texture2D empty, Texture2D full, float health)
    {

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        RenderTarget2D healthBarTarget = new RenderTarget2D(Game1.graphics.GraphicsDevice, full.Width, full.Height);


        Game1.graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(healthBarTarget);
        spriteBatch.Draw(empty, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
        Game1.graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

        spriteBatch.End();
        return (Texture2D)healthBarTarget;
    }
```

the texture is purple.

When inserting Game1.graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear the texture has the clear color.

Why doesn't the sprite batch work?

Comment: Try moving your calls to `GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget` outside of your calls to `SpriteBatch.Begin` and `SpriteBatch.End`.

Comment: No problem, let me write this up in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of `SpriteBatch` is to save its actual call to the GPU until you call `.End()`, rather than immediately (available by optional argument) when you call `.Draw()`.  This allows it to reduce the total number of draw calls it makes, which is an important optimization.  But switching the render target back *before* calling `End()` means that the draw goes to the wrong place, not the `RenderTarget` that was set when you called `Draw()`.

So, call `End()` before switching the target back to the default.